# При получении данных получаю исключение Entity Framework 6.0.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Изучаю Entity Framework 6.0.1, есть таблица один ко многим, после чтения данных я передаю класс User в другую форму в которой мне нужно прочитать Role юзера но там null, я знаю что с помощью DbContext можно с лямбдо выражением сделать нечто подобное

```
foreach(User user in db.Users.Include(p=>p.Role))
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", user.Name);
```

Но мне этот вариант не подходит так как модель класса User я уже передал в другую форму тоесть с БД я не читаю данные но и не понимаю как получить поле с наименованием роли ?
Подскажите как сделать правильно реализацию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам класс для понимания

```
 public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Login { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public int? RoleId { get; set; }
        public int? SalonId { get; set; }
        public virtual Role? Role { get; set; }
        public virtual Salon? Salon { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот так выглядит класс Role

```
public class Role 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

        public Role()
        {
            Users = new List<User>();
        }

    }
```

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) - в EF Core есть три способа загрузки связанных данных. Какой-нибудь один из них вы обязаны использовать. Вы не использовали ни один. / Кстати, какую именно версию EF используете? Ибо есть нюансы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поправил

Comment: Примечание: передавать сущность (entity) куда-либо ещё - это плохо, не рекомендуется так делать. Обычно для этого используют DTO и т. п.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну DTO как я правильно понимаю это дубликат класса для работы с сущностью ? Некая прокладка между сущностью и разработчиком ?

Comment: [Loading Related Entities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) - способы загрузки связанных данных в EF 6. | Вам проще всего будет включить ленивую загрузку (Lazy Loading). Но от неё постепенно отказываются.

Comment: Почему отказываются  ? какие есть нюансы ?

Comment: DTO - это прокладка между слоями приложения. В частности, между формами.

Comment: От ленивой загрузки отказываются, потому что можно _случайно_ всю базу на клиента вытянуть... Были случаи. Потом долго били разрабов...

Comment: Есть ссылка почитать про DTO ?

Comment: Стоп, погодите-ка. У вас и так `virtual Role` - это должно обеспечить ленивую загрузку. Может [отключена](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#turn-off-lazy-loading-for-all-entities)?

Comment: В том-то и дело, я думаю я где-то, что-то, упустил (

Comment: _есть таблица один ко многим_ - я вижу только один-к-одному.

Comment: я нашел ошибку в том что не прописал UseLazyLoadingProxies(). Но пытаясь добавить его получаю ошибку определения (

Comment: Это метод EF Core. А у вас EF 6.

Comment: Да вы правы, но установка пакета Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies всё решает. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Можете оформить как ответ, я закрою тему

Comment: Стало быть, вы используете версию **Core**. | ЗЫ: Как мне это надоело...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Извините, я не досмотрел какая именно версия стоит ((( Не обижайтесь .... Я не со зла. Оформите ответ я Вас хоть так отблагадарю